# Tomcat 6 Errors out on Startup

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, seam, c3p0

I have apache-tomcat-6.0.35 installed locally on my Windows 7 Machine. I also do have Hiberanate Java application that I am trying to run on Tomcat. The RDBMS used on back end is Oracle 11g and hence I do have Oracle client(11.2.0) installed on my machine. The Java app is using c3p0-0.9.1.2 to create connection pool with Oracle in the back end. All the connection information are stored in tnsnames.ora file.

The entire project code is in Version Control System and hence the exact same code runs with no problem on my co-worker's machine but Tomcat fails to launch on mine with the following log. I have had this problem since early this year (Feb 2012) but never got it resolved. I am trying one more time to see if anyone can notice something that I am missing. I appreciate your time looking into this issue! **Thank you much!**

### Here is the content from log file  after I run the Tomcat Server:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:                 "C:\Users\MyName\.IntelliJIdea11\system\tomcat\Unnamed_cerdoafebd8b4"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache\Tomcat6\apache-tomcat-6.0.35"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache\Tomcat6\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache\Tomcat6\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin\bootstrap.jar"
...
2012-10-29T03:37:54.054Z INFO   [main] EnvironmentProperties  - Filtering properties using environment dev
2012-10-29T03:38:51.693Z INFO   [main] MLog  - MLog clients using log4j logging.
2012-10-29T03:39:40.497Z INFO   [main] C3P0Registry  - Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built 21-May-2007 15:04:56; debug? true; trace: 10]
2012-10-29T03:39:45.066Z INFO   [main] AbstractPoolBackedDataSource  - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@f1bda9a6 [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@1091d257 [ acquireIncrement -> 1, acquireRetryAttempts -> 3, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 2zggjq8q1bc3mwlm6u21f|3bf60430, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 2, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 604800, maxIdleTime -> 7200, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 120, maxPoolSize -> 10, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 2, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@7c977f23 [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 2zggjq8q1bc3mwlm6u21f|2bbef4c6, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:oracle:thin:@TRACKER_DEV, properties -> {user=******, .username=cerdo_app, password=******, .password=PEOPLE_WHOUSE_ADHOC, url.dev=jdbc:oracle:thin:@TRACKER_DEV, .url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@DW_DEV, .url.dev=jdbc:oracle:thin:@DW_DEV} ], preferredTestQuery -> select 1 from dual, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> true, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 2zggjq8q1bc3mwlm6u21f|293a985, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
oracle.net.TNSAddress.SOException
    at oracle.net.TNSAddress.ServiceAlias.initFromNVPair(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.TNSAddress.ServiceAlias.initFromString(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAddrTree(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.connect(TTC7Protocol.java:1213)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.logon(TTC7Protocol.java:209)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:252)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:365)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:260)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you use in order to establish the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the properties revealed the line beginning

```
2012-10-29T03:39:45.066Z INFO   [main] AbstractPoolBackedDataSource  - Initializing c3p0 pool...
```

You'll find that the JDBC URL you are trying to connect to is jdbc:oracle:thin:@TRACKER_DEV I suspect that your colleague, after checking the app out from source control, runs some kind of a build script to substitute variables like @TRACKER_DEV and @DW_DEV in various config files. (You might find these variables are set in Tomcat config files, or they could be set in c3p0 config files, e.g. c3p0.properties or c3p0-config.xml.) It's unsurprising you are having connection errors with the JDBC url shown above.

Good luck!

Comment: After replacing @TRACKER_DEV in JDBC URL, I am getting java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection refused... error. This is how my JDBC URL Look now: hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host.company.com)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ord350a.int.company.com))). Any thoughts?? Also, Thank you for replying!

Comment: hi. i think you want to verify your connection info. I'm not expert re "Oracle Net connection descriptor", which is the format you are using, but looking at examples here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/urls.htm#BEIJFHHB I think SERVICE_NAME usually would not be a fully qualified hostname. Can you try the more ordinary jdbc:oracle:thin:[username/password]@//myhost:1521/myservicename format? You might try a simple test program that avoids all the muck of Tomcat and Connection pools, just calls DriverManager.getConnection(). Once you get that to work, the rest might be easy.

Comment: Hi Steve, Actually the problem was the JDK 1.6 being used was in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_27 folder. My JAVA_HOME was set to the above mentioned folder but was never being used by Intellij. To resolve this, I set my JAVA_HOME to C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_27 and my code is working like a charm. Thank you for your insights.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, here are the details of the problem and solution (I worked with ThapaKaji offline on it):

The problem ended up being that the JVM had two Oracle drivers on its classpath, one an old 10g version and the other a newer 11g version (we discovered it because "oracle.net.TNSAddress.ServiceAlias" doesn't exist in the 11g driver). The reason it had two versions and he didn't know it was that the old version was coming from a "classes12.jar" that was hiding in his JDK's jre/lib/ext folder.

The solution to the problem was to remove that JAR, or switch to a different JRE that didn't have that file there.

Answer (score 0):

If this works on your co-worker's machine and does not work on yours the most relevant reason is firewall. Check personal firewall on your machine. I believe it is blocking the connection.

If it does not help check your network configuration. Is it possible that you and your co-worker are in different subnets and other firewall blocks you?

Comment: Thank you for looking into this AlexR. However, Even after disabling every firewall on my Windows 7, I still encounter the same problem. Both me and my co-worker are in same corporate network.